# ffmpeg generated video is mute after seeking it forward

Tags: ffmpeg, video, vlc-media-player

The video is mute after seeking it forward, it was created with ffmpeg. When I play it normally (without seek it) the audio played, I am a Linux user and test it with VLC player and mpv player.

I generated it with this:

```
ffmpeg  -i video.flv -i audio1.flv -i audio2.flv -i audio3.flv -i audio4.flv -i audio5.flv  -i audio6.flv  -i audio7.flv  -i audio8.flv  \
-filter_complex "\
[0:v]tpad=start_duration=29.429[v];\
[1:a]adelay=3654.0[a1];\
[2:a]adelay=53563.0[a2];\
[3:a]adelay=1148851.0[a3];\
[4:a]adelay=1313774.0[a4];\
[5:a]adelay=1373197.0[a5];\
[6:a]adelay=2061735.0[a6];\
[7:a]adelay=2736617.0[a7];\
[8:a]adelay=3387278.0[a8];\
[a1][a2][a3][a4][a5][a6][a7][a8]amix=inputs=8[a]"\
 -map "[v]"  -map "[a]"  -c:v libx264 -crf 23 -c:a mp3 -s 500x500 -shortest ./output.flv
```

`[1:a]` and `[5:a]` is a main audio (the other audio segments have a small duration). If I seek after 1373197.0 ms the video has is mute (when `[5:a]` must be played).